# RewriteEngine Conflicting with each other

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteRule ^upload uploadArea.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^u/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/uploads uploads.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to make `domain.com/upload` to access `uploadArea.php` 
 and `domain.com/u/user_id/uploads` to access `uploads.php?user=user_id`

But somehow, both `domain.com/upload` and `domain.com/u/user_id/uploads` URLs are accessing `uploadArea.php` file.

What is the actual problem? Also suggest any better way to do this.

Comment: `^upload` of course matches on `uploadArea.php` again. You should anchor this pattern not only at the start with `^`, but also at the end with `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure to place your .htaccess file along with your uploads.php file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Internal rewrite rules for without query string.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^upload/?$ [NC] uploadArea.php [NC,L]

##Internal rewrite rules for with query string.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)/uploads?$ [NC] uploadArea.php?user=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: @Mahbub Tonoy, make sure to clear your browser cache please before you testing your URLs.